# Have I had lunch yet?

Tags: code-golf, date

You love lunch. However, you are on a diet and want to make sure you don't accidentally eat lunch twice in one day. So you need to make a program to help you make sure.

However, one complication is that you eat lunch on a very weird schedule. The time you eat lunch at is **MONTH:DAY PM** (you can use UTC or localized time zone). That's right, if the day is **July 14**, you eat lunch at **7:14 PM**.

For your program, you need to use the current date and time (don't take input), and output a consistent truthy value if you have already eaten lunch for the day (or it is lunch time now), or a consistent falsy value if you haven't.

**Examples:** (Time you run program => output)

- May 4th 11:35 AM => false (you will eat lunch at 5:04 PM)
- June 3rd 5:45 PM => false (you will eat lunch at 6:03 PM)
- July 28th 8:30 PM => true (you ate lunch at 7:28 PM)
- December 15th 3:25 PM => true (you ate lunch at 12:15 PM)
- February 29th 2:29 PM => true (it is exactly lunch time)
- October 12th 12:00 AM => false (day just started)

**Reference:**

[How a 12 hour clock works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock)

Comment: Can't we use UTC instead?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yeah, actually that's ok. I'll clarify.

Comment: If you eat lunch only at one specific time of day, how could you eat it twice? =p

Comment: How do you want seconds handled?

Comment: @Stilez Basically ignore them.

Comment: The fact that noon isn't 12AM makes this trickier.

Comment: Does it have to work in future years?

Comment: @MarkS. At least this century, let's say.

Comment: Doesn't everyone eat their lunch like this? Is it really only me?

Answer (score 7):

## [Swift 3](https://swift.org), 310 bytes

```swift
import Foundation;var n=String(describing:Date());var k=n.startIndex;print(Int(n[n.index(k,offsetBy:5)...n.index(k,offsetBy:6)])!*60+Int(n[n.index(k,offsetBy:8)...n.index(k,offsetBy:9)])!+720<=Int(n[n.index(k,offsetBy:11)...n.index(k,offsetBy:12)])!*60+Int(n[n.index(k,offsetBy:14)...n.index(k,offsetBy:15)])!)
```

[Check it out!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/5969d5d9233cfd6caeb2c54c)

This prints `true` and `false`, for truthy and falsy respectively.

> **NOTE**: This only works until the year 9999, at 11:59:59 PM, because it uses Strings to compare the dates.

Comment: Swifts substringing always pains me to look at >_< :P

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s> 18 bytes

```
žežb‚žf12+ža‚т*+`‹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6L7Uo/uSHjXMOrovzdBI@@i@RCD7YpOWdsKjhp3//wMA)

#### Explanation

```
žežb‚žf12+ža‚т*+`‹
že                 # Push current day
  žb               # Push current minute
    ‚              # Wrap to array
     žf12+         # Push current month and add 12 to it
       ža          # Push current hour
         ‚         # Wrap these two to array as well
          т*       # Multiply each element in the second array by 100
            +      # Add both arrays together
             `     # Flatten the resulting array to stack
              ‹    # Is the first item smaller than the second one?
```

Comment: I don't think this works. Because it's 12:51 AM UTC right now, and it's outputting 1.

Comment: Nvm just realized i was checking against am not pm. Fixed at the cost of 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 61 bytes

```matlab
diff(str2num([(d=datestr(now,'mmddHHMM'))(1:4);d(5:8)]))>1200
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/JTMtTaO4pMgorzRXI1ojxTYlsSQVyNfIyy/XUc/NTUnx8PD1VdfU1DC0MtG0TtEwtbLQjNXUtDM0MjD4/x8A)

#### Explanation:

First the functions:

- `now()` returns the time on a decimal format. The parentheses are optional.
- `datestr` converts a decimal number to a string on the format given in its second argument
- `str2num` converts a string to a number
- `diff` takes the difference between two numbers

#### Breakdown:

We take this from the middle:

```matlab
diff(str2num([(d=datestr(now,'mmddHHMM'))(1:4);d(5:8)]))>1200
```

**`datestr(now,'mmddHHMM')`**: First we take the current time `now` as input to `datestr` and specifies the format `mmddHHMM`. The letters mean: `mm = month`, `dd = day`, `HH = hour`, `MM = minutes` and `AM` specifies that the hours should be on a 12-hour format. No separators are included, to keep it as short as possible. It outputs [`d = 07142117`](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/xTYlsSS1uKRIIy@/XEc9NzclxcPD19fRV13z/38A) on the time of writing this explanation. I'll refer to that part as `x` from now.

**`[(d=x)(1:4);d(5:8)]`**: Stores the string above, as `d`, then creates an array with two elements, the first four characters, then the 5-9 characters. This [gives](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/WiPFNiWxJLW4pEgjL79cRz03NyXFw8PX19FXXVNTw9DKRNM6RcPUykIz9v9/AA):

```matlab
ans =
0714
2122
```

Where the numbers are stored as strings, not numbers. We'll call the result above for `y` below.

**`str2num(y)`** converts the array of characters to numbers, where each row turns into one number. This gives `[714; 2122]`. We'll call the result for `z`.

**`diff(z)>1200`** takes the difference between the two numbers and checks if the current time is 1200 higher than the current date. This accounts for AM/PM. This gives us the desired result.

Comment: does this check if it's actually PM?

Comment: It does now. :)

Comment: If "mmdd" is "1201" and "HHMM" is "1215" this should be trueish, no? I had to use mod 12 on the month to account for that somehow.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>22</s> <s>21</s> 20 bytes

```
<0+g.d7.d5-.d6+12.d4
```

*-1 byte thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

[Try this!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3C0%2Bg.d7.d5-.d6%2B12.d4&debug=0)

### old approach, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```
<+`+12.d4.d5+`.d6.d7
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3C%2B%60%2B12.d4.d5%2B%60.d6.d7&debug=0)

### explanation

```
<0+g.d7.d5-.d6+12.d4
              +12.d4   # Add 12 to the current month to make it PM
          -.d6         # subtract that from the current hour: negative it is too early,
                       # positive when it is past this hour, zero when its the same hour
   g.d7.d5             # Is the minute greater or equal than the day? True=1; False=0
  +                    # Add this to the hour result,
                       # so that 0 can turn positive if minutes are true
<0                     # Is the result larger than 0 ?
```

Comment: Wouldn't `&g.d6+.d4 12g.d5.d7` work for 19 bytes? I am not sure and haven't really tested it yet but...

Comment: `&g.d6+12.d4g.d5.d7` would be 18 actually. Also, in the old approach I don't think you need the `\``, and that would become 18 bytes long. I don't know, I might be wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder if you use & then both have to be true e.g. in your code 22:17 wouldn't count as after 19:15, because the minutes are false. I can remove some of the ```, but not all of them. Thank you for saving me a byte.

Comment: Ok, I really didn't know if that was correct, I'm still learning Pyth :P

Comment: Then, I have found an alternative solution `g++720.d5*60.d4+*60.d6.d7`, but that is longer unfortunately (25 bytes). However, it might be a source of inspiration and I figured I should mention it.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <strike>135</strike> 129 bytes

```haskell
import Data.Time
x(ZonedTime(LocalTime d(TimeOfDay h m _))_)|(_,x,y)<-toGregorian d=return(mod x 12<h-12&&y<m)
y=getZonedTime>>=x
```

this unpacking is quite annoying, maybe string handling is better suited

//edit: pattern guards safe 5 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## C#, 174 bytes

```cs
using System;public class Program{public static void Main(){Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now>DateTime.Today.AddHours(DateTime.Today.Month+12).AddMinutes(DateTime.Today.Day));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYqxCsIwEEB/JWODWNC1IIgODlYEC85nctSDNie5i1JKvz0qiINOj/d4TuaOI@achEJrToMo9tUtXTpyxnUgYo6R2wj9@ImioC/cmbypgUJhxw0H4Q7LcyTFPQUstqDYUI/lgR@rrzTsYSjX3u84RSl@es1Br7PF0r6PmkJS/Hu2MFhbTVPOTw)

Comment: I don't think you can add hours and minutes, you must set them.

Comment: Create an anonymous action (`()=>...`) as `Action<bool>` to save bytes. Use `DateTime.Now` when accessing the month and day. In general `public` is not needed and `Program` can be just one letter. Use `using D=System.DateTime;` to save bytes.Overall nice idea but could be golfed a lot. Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder thanks for the advice! This was my first go at code golf but I'll definitely be trying more!

Answer (score 2):

## **PHP and other languages with these common functions: about 28 to 29 bytes:**

```php
echo eval(date('Gi-1199>md'));
```

or alternatively

```php
<?=eval(date('Gi-1199>md'))?>
```

both of which will print.

possibly with `?1:0` depending on representation.  Possibly bytes cut if a language is used that has implicit echo, or no final ';'.

Why would one get the values into variables and all the rest, when it's not needed :)
`date()` leaves anything as literals that isn't defined, so for example, `7 May 2017 17:22:43` passes the expression `1722 - 1200 >= 507` to eval(). Byte saved by changing it to the equivalent `1722 - 1199 > 507`.

Who says eval is dead? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>65</s> <s>64</s> 62 bytes

#### 3 Programs

```mathematica
p=Date[][[#]]&;{60,1}.#&/@(p[4;;5]>=p[2;;3]+{12+p@2~Mod~12,0})
```

```mathematica
{60,1}.#&/@(#[[4;;5]]>=#[[2;;3]]+{12+#[[2]]~Mod~12,0})&@Date[]
```

```mathematica
{60,1}.#&/@(#[4;;5]>=#[2;;3]+{12+#@2~Mod~12,0})&[Date[][[#]]&]
```

These are each one byte less if `≥` counts as a single byte in Mathematica.

#### Explanations

1. `Date[]` returns a list in the form `{y,m,d,h,m,s}`. So
   `Date[][[4;;5]]` are the hours and minutes of the current time.
2. `p=Date[][[#]]&;` makes `p` a function that takes in the indices we
   want and gives us those parts of the date.
3. `{60,1}.#&` is an anonymous function that takes the dot product of `{60,1}` and the input to get a way to compare times. It's one byte shorter than `TimeObject`.
4. `p@2` is equivalent to `p[2]`, the number of the month.
5. `+{12+p@2~Mod~12,0}` adds `{12,0}` to the month and date when we're not in December, and adds `{0,0}` otherwise. (Thanks, michi7x7!)
6. `>=` is the comparison operator, but we can't compare {hours, minutes} to {adjusted month, date} entrywise...
7. `/@` maps `{60,1}.#&` to both sides of the inequality in parentheses, so we can compare times correctly.
8. For the programs that start with `{60,1}.#&`, they use `#` to represent the input to a big anonymous function, and `&` to signify the end.
9. `@Date[]` Applies the big function on its line (which extracts parts of a list) to the date list itself.
10. `[Date[][[#]]&]` Applies the big function on its line to another anonymous function, one which extracts parts of the date list.

#### Bonus

As an aside, if we ate lunch between 1AM and 12:59PM, then we could save 25 bytes with just `{60,1}.#&[Date[][[#]]]&/@(4;;5>=2;;3)`.

You can test all of these out by pasting the code into the [Wolfram Cloud sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com/) and clicking Gear->Evaluate Cell or hitting Shift+Enter or Numpad Enter.

Comment: I believe that your bonus note is actually a valid solution - as your domain of valid times is `13:01` to `24:31`

Comment: @TaylorScott Thanks for the code formatting (though the colorization seems to fail on some trickier cases). I'm not sure I understand your comment, though. If the If it's 7:20AM on July 19, then the "bonus" code would say "yes, you've had lunch" even though it's far from 7:20PM. The OP has test cases in the AM so I think this makes it invalid. What am I missing?

Comment: @Mark_S. I See - for some reason i had read that as being 11:59 PM rather than 12:59 -is there no concise way to add 12 hours to the bonus code?

Comment: @TaylorScott Well, we want to add 12 to the hour for most months so for January through November we could replace the `Date[]` in the bonus with  `(Date[]+{0,12,0,0,0,0})` (there may be a way to golf that, but `12UnitVector[6,2]` is longer). The problem is that on dates like December 3, we eat lunch at 12:03, not 24:03, so we need to add 12 *except in December*. This requires us to either 1. peek inside the date to see if we're in December or not (as in my answers), or 2. write a function that examines if we went to 24:XX after the fact, which would be longer.

Comment: @MarkS. 12+Mod[#[[2]],12] ?

Comment: @michi7x7 Good idea! Combining with infixing, that saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### Java, 81 bytes

```java
n->new Date().after(new Date(){{setHours(getMonth()+13);setMinutes(getDate());}})
```

[Try it online!](https://ideone.com/x9C7Ty)

Ungolfed:

```java
n -> new Date().after(new Date() { //new Date() returns current date
    { //instance initialization
        setHours(getMonth() + 13); //month + 12 hours for PM + 1 because months are 0 indexed
        setMinutes(getDate()());
    }
})
```

Comment: Does this handle December correctly? I haven't worked with Java in a long time, but this looks like it might send December 1 to 24:01 instead of just after noon.

Comment: Don't forget to include your import of `java.util.Date` in the byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## q, 31 bytes

```
x>12:+"T"$(-3!x:.z.P)5 6 13 8 9
```

Example:

```
q).z.P
2017.07.16D19:35:26.654099000
q)x>12:+"T"$(-3!x:.z.P)5 6 13 8 9
1b
```

Interpreter is available [here](http://kx.com/download)

Old version

```
{x:.z.p;x>"T"$":"sv"0"^2$/:string 12 0+`mm`dd$\:x}`
```

Comment: The `2$` pad will turn `6` to `6_` rather than `_6`, so you'd want `(-2)$`, but you can cancel out those extra 3 chars by using the shorthand for `string ` as `($)`... or instead of using $ to pad, prepend "0" and then take the last 2 chars:

    `{x:.z.P;x>"T"$":"sv -2#'"0",'($)12 0+`mm`dd$\:x}` for 49 bytes

Comment: good spot. the original was invalid. i added an even shorter version

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 104 bytes

```python
from datetime import*
n=datetime.now();print(n>=n.replace(hour=[0,n.month+12][n.month<12],minute=n.day))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCsIwEEbhvafoMqklaF1qvEjpItiRBJx/wjBFevrYRd19PHh1syy4tfZW4W5JRlaYusJV1PoT4j8FyNf5e9UCc3hGBKX6SS9yWVaN02VAYIHl83Wcp8OP3QMXrEb7sKTN@9Z@)

[All datetime tests.](https://tio.run/##jdHBasMgGAfwe57ioztUNylqYlvC0jcY7LBb2UEaQxyJBmPo8vSZa5OmGy2bKHwi/vyrTe9La@JhKJytIZdeeV0r0HVjnX@MclVAgUw2LayMPSKM0whCa5w2HpldZlZONZU8KFTazmV7SsyqtsaXT4y/78f6OdSk1qbzKmzIZY/xcBYWbzZMU1gQUCbPlkscFQhH0fXBiFO2ISAIJAROpzBGYORigTE8QLaDQlatAtTbDo66qkBJD1VnDiWEQqQ0gdcXfAteE4gneHOBk//B65TG9@DQ@XaUOZ0j00n2rhvhsHE2Nynf3jMZD0NMccUF5eIPlPGUiXsqv0rKkhnd/kS1B92C@pQHX/Uj/a3cTkrPaU/ofHtKf71r@H/46FoPrZfOqxwPXw) I replaced Feb 29th with Feb 28th because the invalid date wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 130 bytes

```py
from datetime import*
a=str(datetime.now()).split()
print int(''.join(a[0].split('-')[1:]))+1200<int(''.join(a[1].split(':')[:2]))
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VcpBCsMgEIXhq7hzJiWiLk1zkpCF0JROqI6YgdDTWxdtoYu3@d9XXvLg7Fu7V07qFmUTSpuiVLjKMMX5kArfbDKfgGiO8iQBnEqlLKoPtDY7U4a42PVz61Hj4sKKeHHe2us/cz8WOgu@s9be)

Note: There may be a problem with the sign. Please excuse that because I follow IST and it's quite confusing because it's 2:28am here now. Do correct the sign if you feel it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 75 bytes

```js
f=
(d=new Date)=>(d.getHours()-d.getMonth()-13||d.getMinutes()-d.getDate())>=0
```

```html
<input type=button value=Lunch? onclick=o.textContent=f()><tt id=o>
```

Those long function names...

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 75 bytes

```js
t=new Date,t.setHours(13+t.getMonth()),t.setMinutes(t.getDate()),new Date>t
```

Which is equivalent to the following code:

```js
function didEat()
  const d = new Date()
  d.setHours(12 /* PM */ + d.getMonth() + 1)
  d.setMinutes(d.getDate())
  return new Date > d
}
didEat()
```

Comment: last `t` can be used while modify

Comment: ```t=new Date,t.setMinutes(t.getDate(t.setHours(13+t.getMonth(n=+t))))<n```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 92 bytes

```r
library(lubridate)
d=Sys.Date()
cat(Sys.time()>ymd_hm(paste0(d,'-',month(d)+12,'-',day(d))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcexDYAgEEDRnkU4Ihq118oNHMAcHgkkoAbPgukR/dV/qZTgTcKUITwmeUK2StC05rtb6oMSOzJ8ZB8r5xxpcxEuvNn2QFq2UsfzYAekmmH8TZiraqW8)

```r
                                   month(d)+12,'-',day(d)    # get month and day and paste into a string, adding 12 hours for pm
                      paste0(d,'-',                      )   # add current date to beginning
               ymd_hm(                                    )  # turn whole thing into a date-time object
cat(Sys.time()>                                            ) # compare with current date-time and print
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 45 chars

```perl
sub c{@a=gmtime;$a[2]-12>$a[4]&&$a[1]>=$a[3]}
```

If I have to provide a method, it will be 45 for `sub c{...}`.
If I have to print
`say ()||0` even makes it 47. I will add that in if it's a requirement.

Comment: I believe that because the original question specifies `you need to make a program to help you make sure` that snippets are not allowed - that said either of your listed output methods are generally considered valid

Comment: fair enough, I will provide output then. Thanks for editing, I was not aware of the proper language tag! I was thinking `perl -e` was generally ok, but others have provided functions, so I edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>52</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

```
=TIME(MONTH(NOW())+12,DAY(NOW()),0)<=MOD(NOW(),1)
```

Input is this formula in any cell.
Output is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Excel's built-in date handling helps a lot.
The `TIME` function returns the day's lunch time as a time value which, if converted to a date, would use `Jan 0, 1900`. We compare it against `NOW - TODAY` so we get the current time with a date value of `0` or `Jan 0, 1900`.

<sub><sub>Saved 2 bytes thanks to Wernisch</sub></sub>
<sup><sup>Saved 1 byte thanks to Adam</sup></sup>

Comment: Do you need the extra braces around NOW()-TODAY() ?

Comment: @Wernisch No, as it turns out. I had presumed it would evaluate the inequality before the subtraction but I didn't check it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can save a byte by changing from `now()-today()` to `mod(now(),1)`

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 55 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes no input and outputs a Boolean value representing whether I've had lunch to the VBE immediate window

```vba
n=Now:?TimeValue(n)>TimeValue(Month(n)&":"&Day(n)&"PM")
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 62 chars

```
f=
_=>[,m,d,H,M]=(new Date).toISOString().split(/\D/),+m+12+d<=H+M
```

Test code below:

```js
console.log(( // May 4, 5:03 PM, false (1 minute before lunch)
  [,m,d,H,M]=(new Date("2017-05-04T17:03Z")).toISOString().split(/\D/),+m+12+d<=H+M
));

console.log(( // May 4, 5:04 PM, true (exact time)
  [,m,d,H,M]=(new Date("2017-05-04T17:04Z")).toISOString().split(/\D/),+m+12+d<=H+M
));

console.log(( // May 4, 5:05 PM, true (1 minute after)
  [,m,d,H,M]=(new Date("2017-05-04T17:05Z")).toISOString().split(/\D/),+m+12+d<=H+M
));
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64+7 = 71 bytes

Requires the `-rtime` flag because for some reason `Time::parse` is like, the only function requires it out of the entire `Time` module.

```ruby
p Time.parse("#{t=Time.now}"[/.+-(..)-(..) /]+[$1,$2]*?:+'pm')<t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvxfoBCSmZuql5dfDmMWJBYVp2ooKVeX2MKkapWi9fW0dTX09DTBhIJ@rHa0iqGOilGslr2VtnpBrrqmTcn////yC0oy8/OK/@sWlQC1AgA) (it also prints out the current time)

Answer (score 0):

### Julia 0.6.0 99 bytes

`a=split(string(Dates.today()),"-");(Dates.hour(now())<parse(a[2]))&&Dates.minute(now())<parse(a[3])`

Julia has built in function to use the clock/calendar of the computer.
My computer is running on ubuntu 16.04 and already with 12 hour clock, so I can't say if what I did works with other machine using different clock, but seems to works on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

## Matlab, 241 bytes

```
dt=datestr(now,'mm/dd');
dt(2)
dt(4:5)
CrctLchTm=[' ' dt(2) ':' dt(4:5) ' PM']
CrntTm=datestr(now,'HH:MM PM')
CrntTm(7)=='A'
if ans==1
    Lch='false'
else
    CrctLchTm=str2num([CrctLchTm(2) CrctLchTm(4:5)])
    CrntTm=str2num([CrntTm(2) CrntTm(4:5)])
    CrntTm<CrctLchTm
    if ans==1
        Lch='false'
    else
        Lch='true'             
    end    
end
```

Explanation: First, I obtain the date as a string. Then, I isolate the month and day. Since the problem states that it is always interpreted as PM, then I automatically write false if the time is in AM. If the current time is in PM, then I continue on and just compare the numbers of the time.

Note: I've formatted it slightly differently here for readability.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript ES6, 70 Bytes

```
_=>(h=x=>new Date().toJSON().substr(x,5).replace(/\D/,0))(5)+12e3<h(11)
```

Maybe not that right on some milliseconds...